# How to fix Spark error: not found: value spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have Spark of version 2.2.0 on linux os. Today I launch it using `spark-shell` and input following codes one after another:
`import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD` 
`val rootPath: String = _` 
`val file: String = s"${rootPath}/mytext.txt"` 
`val lineRDD: RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext.textFile(file)`
and the following error was thrown out:
error: not found: value spark 
what should I do to fix it?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The spark context is an object you create in your program, it's not part of the package.

In the spark shell a context is already created for you, called `sc`

So when you want to access spark context in the shell you can write

```
sc.textFile(file)
```

Comment: I took your suggestion and a similar error was thrown out: "error: not found: value sc". Do you know why? Thank you!